# How do I change the center of a 360 video within Adobe Premiere so that there is always a front side (or main point of interest) in each video?

Tags: premiere, 360video

I am trying to make my video so that the main point of interest is always in the same direction. How do I chose which area of the video is in front for each scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Effects > Immersive Video > VR Projection > Pan.

Here you can change "pan" to whatever point you want to focus on.